# @PreRemove not working for many to many relestionship jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, many-to-many

im new in java spring boot
i want implement bookmark with jpa...i can add in my list of bookmark entity but for remove i have trouble(my function not working) whats wrong with my code?

Place entity

```
 @JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Bookmark> bookmark_places;
//@JoinTable(name = "bookmark_place",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookmark_id",referencedColumnName = "id" ),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id",referencedColumnName = "id"))
public Place(int placeId){
    this.placeId = placeId;
}


@Transactional
@PreRemove
public void deletePlaceList(){

    for (Bookmark b :bookmark_places){
        b.getPlaces().remove(this);
    }
}
```

bookmark entity

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "bookmark")
public class Bookmark {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;
    @Column(name ="user_id")
    private Long userid;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "bookmark_places",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookmark_id"
           ,referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id",
    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Place> places;
```

and bookmarkRepositoryTest:

```
    @SpringBootTest
        class BookmarkRepositoryTest
        {
            @Autowired
            private BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository;
@Autowired
    private PlaceRepository placeRepository;
        @Test
        @PreRemove
            public void deletePlace(){
                Long id = Long.valueOf(1);
                Bookmark bookmark = bookmarkRepository.findBookmarkByUserid(id);
            
        Long userId = Long.valueOf(1);
        Bookmark bookmark = bookmarkRepository.findBookmarkByUserid(userId);
        Place place = placeRepository.getPlaceByPlaceId(2);
        bookmark.getPlaces().remove(place);
        
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of arguing,i fixed my problem whit changing this line..

```
 @JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Bookmark> bookmark_places;
```

to:

```
@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "places",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Bookmark> bookmark_places;
```

and this line:

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable(name = "bookmark_places",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookmark_id"
       ,referencedColumnName = "id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id",
referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Place> places;
```

to:

```
ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "bookmark_places",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookmark_id"
       ,referencedColumnName = "id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id",
referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Place> places;
```

but i guess my problem was with  trusting the SpringBootTest,
when i run my code with controller and used service interface and,i get the true answer
dont forgot your delete function should be like this:

```
@PreRemove
@Transactional
Bookmark deleteFromBookmark(Long userId,int placeId);
```

and serviceImpl class:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements BookmarkService{
     @Override
    public Bookmark deleteFromBookmark(Long userId , int placeId)
    {
        Bookmark bookmark = bookmarkRepository.findBookmarkByUserid(userId);
        Place place =  placeRepository.getPlaceByPlaceId(placeId);
        bookmark.getPlaces().remove(place);
        return bookmark;
    }
}
```